# SavedChanges event in EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1

SavingChanges event of DBContext fires just before saves are sent to DB.

Is there an event somewhere I can subscribe which fires just AFTER save is complete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no - there is no such event.
More context regarding what exactly you are trying to achieve and why you want such an event could help in giving a better answer.
A workaround that comes to mind would be overriding the `SaveChanges` method and executing your custom code (or raising your event) after the call to `base.SaveChanges()`. Basically you can do something like in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx), but get it to suit your needs, e.g.:

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{
    int result = base.SaveChanges(options);

    // Do whatever you need to do after saving changes

    return result;
}
```